# Will driving 4 unbalanced tires to a shop for balancing cause any issue on the suspension/alignment?

Tags: tires, suspension, alignment, wheel-balance

I've refinished all 4 aluminum wheels on a 2wd 2001 Toyota Tacoma. In the process, I dismounted the tires (235/70) and flipped them (so the white lettering is on the inside) and removed all existing weights (there were a lot) so the wheels could be completely refinished.

Now that I'm done, I need to drive the truck to a shop to get the wheels balanced.

It'll be a short drive, and I shouldn't need to go over 30-35mph.

- Question 1) Will this cause any issue on the suspension/alignment?
- Question 2) I've had an alignment in the last 2 years. Would flipping
  the tires impact this/should I get it re-aligned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of balance will not damage your vehicle in the short term. If it is severe and you do it for a LONG period of time, it can damage your shocks, then your springs. Eventually  your bushings will wear out as well. More than likely the imbalance will be at a much higher speed and you won't even notice it at the slower speeds. Taking it to the shop is not an issue.

As far as alignment goes, rotating the tires will not cause you any issues with the alignment. Realistically, one has nothing to do with the other.